# In Biqquery, how to filter an array of Struct on matching multiple fields in the Struct using Standard Sql?

Tags: google-bigquery

Here is the record layout of the table  (load_history) I am trying to use filter on using Standard Sql (because legacy sql will probably become obsolete at some point):

```
[
{
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "Job",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "fields": [
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "name",
          "type": "STRING"
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "start_time",
          "type": "TIMESTAMP"
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "end_time",
          "type": "TIMESTAMP"
        },
        {
    ]
},      
{
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "name": "source",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "description": "source tables touched by this job",
    "fields": [     
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "database",
          "type": "STRING"
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "schema",
          "type": "STRING"
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "table",
          "type": "STRING"
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "partition_time",
          "type": "TIMESTAMP"
        }    
    ]
}
]
```

I need to filter and select only records where there is an entry in array "source" whose  "schema" & "table" fields match certain values (ex. schema='log' AND table='customer' in the same array entry).

The following works when filtering only on one field in the Struct (schema name) :

```
select name, array(select x from unnest(schema) as x where x ='log' ), table
from (select job.name , array(select schema from unnest(source)) as schema, 
      array(select table from unnest(source)) as table
      from  config.load_history)
```

However, I can't make it work to filter on combination of fields in the same array entry.

Would appreciate your help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT data
FROM data, UNNEST(source) AS s
WHERE (s.schema, s.table) = ('log', 'customer')
```

or

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(source) AS s 
  WHERE (s.schema, s.table) = ('log', 'customer')
)
```

you can test/play with it with below dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 
    STRUCT<name STRING, start_time INT64, end_time INT64>('jobA', 1, 2) AS job,
    [STRUCT<database STRING, schema STRING, table STRING, partition_time INT64>
      ('d1', 's1', 't1', 1), 
      ('d1', 's2', 't2', 2), 
      ('d1', 's3', 't3', 3) 
    ] AS source UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    STRUCT<name STRING, start_time INT64, end_time INT64>('jobB', 1, 2) AS job,
    [STRUCT<database STRING, schema STRING, table STRING, partition_time INT64>
      ('d1', 's1', 't1', 1), 
      ('d2', 's4', 't2', 2), 
      ('d2', 's3', 't3', 3) 
    ] AS source 
)
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(source) AS s 
  WHERE (s.schema, s.table) = ('s2', 't2')
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  The first solution is short and sweet and works.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
SELECT
  job.name,
  ARRAY(SELECT schema FROM UNNEST(matching_sources)) AS matching_schemas,
  ARRAY(SELECT table FROM UNNEST(matching_sources)) AS matching_tables
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST(sources)
          WHERE schema = 'log' AND `table` = 'customer') AS matching_sources
  FROM YourTable
)
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(matching_sources) > 0;
```

This would return an array of schemas and an array of tables, where both match the condition, and exclude rows where no entry in the array matches the condition.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to filter and select only records where there is an entry in array "source" whose "schema" & "table" fields match certain values

This sounds like it could be solved with a simple `WHERE` clause, like so:

```
WITH data AS(
  select STRUCT<name STRING, start_time TIMESTAMP, end_time TIMESTAMP> ('job_1', TIMESTAMP("2017-06-10"), TIMESTAMP("2017-06-11")) Job, ARRAY<STRUCT<database STRING, schema STRING, table STRING, partition_time TIMESTAMP> > [STRUCT('database_1', "schema_1", "table_1", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-10")), STRUCT('database_1', "schema_1", "table_2", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-10")), STRUCT('database_1', "schema_3", "table_1", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-10")), STRUCT('database_2', "schema_2", "table_2", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-10"))] source union all
  select STRUCT<name STRING, start_time TIMESTAMP, end_time TIMESTAMP> ('job_2', TIMESTAMP("2017-06-10"), TIMESTAMP("2017-06-11")) Job, ARRAY<STRUCT<database STRING, schema STRING, table STRING, partition_time TIMESTAMP> > [STRUCT('database_2', "schema_2", "table_2", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-10")), STRUCT('database_2', "schema_2", "table_3", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-10")), STRUCT('database_1', "schema_1", "table_3", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-10"))] source
)

SELECT
  *
FROM data
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(source) WHERE schema = "schema_2" AND table = "table_2")
```

This will return all rows where, at some point, had a given schema and a given table.

If you want to filter out in the output only the records with the matched filters, you could also run this:

```
SELECT
  job.*,
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT database, schema, table, partition_time FROM UNNEST(source) WHERE schema = "schema_2" AND table = "table_2") filtered_data
FROM data
  WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(source) WHERE schema = "schema_2" AND table = "table_2")
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you want in your question but it might give you an idea on how to filter out values from ARRAYs.

Answer (score 0):

As it was well  explained  by Mikhail-berlyant  https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221944/mikhail-berlyant
I used the first example.

```
SELECT data
FROM data, UNNEST(source) AS s
WHERE (s.schema, s.table) = ('log', 'customer')
```

let me explain this on my exaple:
If I want to get the exact matching rows with concrete cpc code  from google public patents

Normally I'do it with the Like condition

```
SELECT cpc
FROM
`patents-public-data.patents.publications`
where cpc like "%G01R31/007"
```

I can't use that in this purpose cause  the CPC cell contains an Array list [{'code': 'G01R31/007', 'inventive': True, 'first': False, 'tree': []}]

So i need to divide this array into blocks, and i'm addressing to the **code** identificator and equating my query with the exact value that i want to extract  -- in may case it's **G01R31/007**

here the code below:

```
SELECT publication_number, cpc
FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications`, 
UNNEST(cpc) AS s
WHERE (s.code) = ('G01R31/007')
```